# Dictionary size reduces upon increasing one element

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I ran this:

```
import sys

diii = {'key1':1,'key2':2,'key3':1,'key4':2,'key5':1,'key6':2,'key7':1}
print sys.getsizeof(diii)
# output: 1048

diii = {'key1':1,'key2':2,'key3':1,'key4':2,'key5':1,'key6':2,'key7':1,'key8':2}
print sys.getsizeof(diii)
# output: 664
```

Before asking here, I restarted my python shell and tried it online too and got the same result.
I thought a dictionary with one more element will either give same bytes as output or more, than the one containing one less element.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Using dict literals, dicts have "size"  280 bytes for 0-5 keys, 1048 bytes for 6 or 7 keys, then 664 for 8-10.  Using dictcomps the size is 280 for 0-5 keys, then 1048 until 22 keys.  There must be some quirk in how pre-sizing works for literals.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Previous answers have already mentioned that you needn't worry, so I will dive into some more technical details. It's long, but please bear with me.

**TLDR**: this has to do with arithmetic of resizing. Each resize allocates `2**i` memory, where `2**i > requested_size; 2**i >= 8`, but then each insert resizes the underlying table further if 2/3 of slots are filled, but this time the `new_size = old_size * 4`. This way, your first dictionary ends up with 32 cells allocated while the second one with as little as 16 (as it got a bigger initial size upfront).

**Answer**: As @snakecharmerb noted in the comments this depends on the way that the dictionary is created. For the sake of brevity, let me refer you to [this, excellent blog post](https://doughellmann.com/blog/2012/11/12/the-performance-impact-of-using-dict-instead-of-in-cpython-2-7-2/) which explains the differences between the `dict()` constructor and the dict literal `{}` on both Python bytecode and CPython implementation levels.

Let's start with the magic number of 8 keys. It turns out to be a constant, predefined for Python's 2.7 implementation in [dictobject.h](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Include/dictobject.h#L48) headers file
 - the minimal size of the Python dictionary:

```
/* PyDict_MINSIZE is the minimum size of a dictionary.  This many slots are
 * allocated directly in the dict object (in the ma_smalltable member).
 * It must be a power of 2, and at least 4.  8 allows dicts with no more
 * than 5 active entries to live in ma_smalltable (and so avoid an
 * additional malloc); instrumentation suggested this suffices for the
 * majority of dicts (consisting mostly of usually-small instance dicts and
 * usually-small dicts created to pass keyword arguments).
 */
#define PyDict_MINSIZE 8
```

As such, it may differ between the specific Python implementations, but let's assume that we all use the same CPython version. However, the dict of size 8 is expected to neatly contain only 5 elements; don't worry about this, as this specific optimization is not as important for us as it seems.

Now, when you create the dictionary using the dict literal `{}`, CPython takes a shortcut (as compared to the explicit creation when calling `dict` constructor). Simplifying a bit the bytecode operation `BUILD_MAP` gets resolved and it results in calling the `_PyDict_NewPresized` function which will construct a dictionary for which we already know the size upfront:

```
/* Create a new dictionary pre-sized to hold an estimated number of elements.
   Underestimates are okay because the dictionary will resize as necessary.
   Overestimates just mean the dictionary will be more sparse than usual.
*/

PyObject *
_PyDict_NewPresized(Py_ssize_t minused)
{
    PyObject *op = PyDict_New();

    if (minused>5 && op != NULL && dictresize((PyDictObject *)op, minused) == -1) {
        Py_DECREF(op);
        return NULL;
    }
    return op;
}
```

This function calls the normal dict constructor (`PyDict_New`) and requests a resize of the newly created dict - but only if it is expected to hold more than 5 elements. This is due to an optimization which allows Python to speed up some things by holding the data in the pre-allocated "smalltable", without invoking expensive memory allocation and de-allocation functions.

Then, the `dictresize` will try to determine the minimal size of the new dictionary. It will also use the magic number 8 - as the starting point and iteratively multiply by 2 until it finds the minimal size larger than the requested size. For the first dictionary, this is simply 8, however, for the second one (and all dictionaries created by dict literal with less than 15 keys) it is 16.

Now, in the `dictresize` function there is [a special case](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/dictobject.c#L623) for the former, smaller `new_size == 8`, which is meant to bring forward the aforementioned optimization (using the "small table" to reduce memory manipulation operations). However, because there is no need to resize the newly created dict (e.g. no elements were removed so far thus the table is "clean") nothing really happens.

On the contrary, when the `new_size != 8`, a usual procedure of reallocating the hash table follows. This ends up with a new table being allocated to store the 
"big" dictionary. While this is intuitive (the bigger dict got a bigger table), this does not seem to move us forward to the observed behavior yet - but, please bear with me one more moment.

Once we have the pre-allocated dict, STORE_MAP optcodes tell the interpreter to insert consecutive key-value pairs. This is implemented with `dict_set_item_by_hash_or_entry` function, which - importantly - resizes the dictionary after each increase in size (i.e. successful insertion) if more than 2/3 of the slots are already used up. The size will increase x4 ([in our case](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/dictobject.c#L802), for large dicts only by x2).

So here is what happens when you create the dict with 7 elements:

```
# note 2/3 = 0.(6)
BUILD_MAP   # initial_size = 8, filled = 0
STORE_MAP   # 'key_1' ratio_filled = 1/8 = 0.125, not resizing
STORE_MAP   # 'key_2' ratio_filled = 2/8 = 0.250, not resizing
STORE_MAP   # 'key_3' ratio_filled = 3/8 = 0.375, not resizing
STORE_MAP   # 'key_4' ratio_filled = 4/8 = 0.500, not resizing
STORE_MAP   # 'key_5' ratio_filled = 5/8 = 0.625, not resizing
STORE_MAP   # 'key_6' ratio_filled = 6/8 = 0.750, RESIZING! new_size = 8*4 = 32
STORE_MAP   # 'key_7' ratio_filled = 7/32 = 0.21875
```

And you end up with a dict having a total size of 32 elements in the hash table.

**However, when adding eight elements the initial size will be twice bigger (16), thus we will never resize as the condition `ratio_filled > 2/3` will never be satisfied!**

And that's why you end up with a smaller table in the second case.

Answer (score 7):

`sys.getsizeof` returns the memory allocated to the underlying hash table implementation of those dictionaries, which has a somewhat non-obvious relationship with the actual size of the dictionary.

The CPython implementation of Python 2.7 quadruples the amount of memory allocated to a hash table each time it's filled up to 2/3 of its capacity, but shrinks it if it has over allocated memory to it (i.e. a large contiguous block of memory has been allocated but only a few addresses were actually used).

It just so happens that dictionaries that have between 8 and 11 elements allocate just enough memory for CPython to consider them 'over-allocated', and get shrunk.

Comment: According to [the docs for the BUILD_MAP opcode](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/dis.html#opcode-BUILD_MAP), the dictionaries it creates are _pre-sized_ for the number of items in the literal. So is the dictionary created and then immediately shrunk?

Comment: @snakecharmerb, dg-vwp - I wrote a bit more details in my answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56315369/6646912). dg-vwp's answer is good and concise one, though the last paragraph is not strictly true (they do not get shrunk, just never get big enough).

Answer (score 2):

You're not doing anything wrong. The size of a dictionary doesn't exactly correspond to the number of elements, as dictionaries are overallocated and dynamically resized once a certain percentage of their memory space is used. I'm not sure what makes the dict smaller in 2.7 (it doesn't in 3) in your example, but you don't have to worry about it. Why are you using 2.7 and why do you want to know the exact memory usage of the dict (which btw doesn't include the memory used by the variables contained in the dictionary, as the dictionary itself is filled with pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Allocation of dict literals is handled here: [dictobject.c#L685-L695](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/dictobject.c#L685-L695).

Due to quirks of the implementation, size vs number of elements does not end up being [monotonically increasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function).

```
import sys

def getsizeof_dict_literal(n):
    pairs = ["{0}:{0}".format(i) for i in range(n)]
    dict_literal = "{%s}" % ", ".join(pairs)
    source = "sys.getsizeof({})".format(dict_literal)
    size = eval(source)
    return size
```

The odd growing-and-shrinking behaviour exhibited is not just a weird once-off accident, it's a regularly repeating occurrence. For the first few thousand results, the visualization looks like this:

[image: dict literal sizes py2]

In more recent versions of Python, the dict implementation is completely different and allocation details are more sane.  See [bpo28731 - `_PyDict_NewPresized()` creates too small dict](https://bugs.python.org/issue28731), for an example of some recent changes. In Python 3.7.3, the visualization now looks like this with smaller dicts in general and a monotonic allocation:

[image: dict literal sizes py3]

Answer (score -1):

You are actually not doing anything wrong. `getsizeof` doesn't get the size of the elements inside the dictionary but the rough estimate of the dictionary. The alternative way for this problem would be `json.dumps()` from the `json` library. Though it doesn't give you the actual size of the object, it is consistent with the changes you make to the object.

Here's an example

```
import sys
import json


diii = {'key1':1,'key2':2,'key3':1,'key4':2,'key5':1,'key6':2,'key7':1}
print sys.getsizeof(json.dumps(diii)) # <----

diii = {'key1':1,'key2':2,'key3':1,'key4':2,'key5':1,'key6':2,'key7':1,'key8':2}
print sys.getsizeof(json.dumps(diii)) # <----
```

`json.dumps()` changes the dictionary into a json string, then `diii` can be evaluated as a string.
Read more about python's `json` library [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp)

Comment: What does json offer that str does not for this application? Why mention it?