# How much ram needed to hold a huge list?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I want to create an empty list of lists:

```
shape = (70000,70000)
corr = np.empty(shape).tolist()
```

How can I know how much RAM I need to hold this list using windows operating system (64 bit)?

Answer (score 3):

This will create a list-of-lists-of-floats. About half of the RAM used is for the floats themselves and half is for the references to them. The size of each reference is 8 bytes and the size of each float is also 8 bytes. That makes 70000 * 70000 * 8 * 2 bytes (approx 80G).

Lists look like this in memory:

[image]

*image source: [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/05/09/why-python-is-slow/)*

The 70001 lists objects themselves also have overhead (they maintain pointer into storage array, and their own length), but this will be negligible in comparison (probably ~4 MB).

Also note that Python lists [overallocate space](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56382873/674039) by an implementation-dependent factor, so consider these numbers a lower bound. Memory is over-allocated so that there are always some free slots available, which makes appends and inserts faster. The space allocated increased by about 12.5% when full.

Comment: do you suggest a better way to do that with less memory?

Comment: Ask why you need a dense list of lists so large. The numpy array should use about half the memory. You can half it again by using float32 instead of float64 dtype. If that's still too big, maybe you can use sparse arrays, or a Python dict.

Comment: *on a 64-bit machine